# Azure Service Bus Single Service having Multiple Topic and Subscriber

Tags: azure, azure-servicebus-topics

I have an Micro-Service which is a Consumer/Subscriber service, that receives messages from other 2 Services.
So, I want this Micro-Service to Subscribe from the other 2 micro-services that have different Topic and Subscription.
The constructing/Initializing the service/Azure Service Bus Properties is as below :

```
services.AddServiceBusNotifications(Configuration, "Communication");
 services.AddServiceBusNotifications(Configuration, "SSO");
```

And the code for Subscribing to this 2 services is as below:

```
var eventBus = applicationBuilder.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IEventBus>(); 

eventBus.Subscribe<MeetinginviteCreatedEvent, MeetinginviteCreatedEventHandler>();

eventBus.Subscribe<NewUserCreatedEvent, NewUserCreatedEventHandler>();
```

So, both the above 2 lines are taking the settings(Topic/Subscription) from the same topic & Subscriber, but I want to take the Topic and Subscription for 2 different Microservices.
How Can I use the Same Subscriber for Multiple Topic and Subscription(Different Microservices).

I have followed the code from the URL : https://github.com/pmchlk/service-bus-messaging

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot going in the code that you've shared since you have a wrapper around the Azure Service Bus SDK but if my understanding of it is correct, one way to solve your issue is to [simply forward messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-auto-forwarding) from the individual subscriptions into another topic/subscription and use that in your service.

This would be simpler if it works like I expect it to, based on my understanding of your code.

The other options would be to either change your Dependency Injection code to register transient Event Bus objects instead of a singleton or update your Event Bus class to handle multiple subscriptions. Both of these would require quite a few changes in your custom implementation.